# Tails anonymous filesharing

Tags: anonymity, tor, dropbox

I performed some research on file sharing and anonymity, but it turns out anything I read is not about what I need.

Most articles and forums recommend not to use services like Google Drive or Dropbox, as they don't run on opensource code so you really need to trust the software to be sure your data is safe. Fair enough, but that is not what I need.

I don't care if the data is safe or not, I just need seamless file sharing, that anybody in the "normal web" can use without having to install complicated software, without ever having to do with command lines etc. I want them to use something mainstream and uncomplicated.

I'd connect to the file sharing website via Tails, and I don't want any of my data (eg IP, DNS, ISP, MAC, approximate location... you name it) to be compromised by this setup.

Of course I'll need to pay much attention to the metadata, to avoid giving away information. But what I'm concerned about is the possibility for the file sharing platform to trace me down through their fancy java functionalities or other tool that may compromise anonymity even if I use Tails.

Today for example I was testing Dropbox.

To my big surprise they do allow Tails users with some very limited captcha checks and double factor email authentication.

The point is, I have no chance to see their log and check where do they think I am from. That's why I'm here asking the experts.

So, to cut a long story short: what would be your best advice to share files and folders with non-anonymous users while staying anonymous, and having them performing all the routine activities they usually perform with file sharing?

After Dropbox, here's my checklist (I haven't visited any of them yet):

- Seafile
- Spideoak
- Tresorit

Comment: There are lots of websites that show you what they know about you. Also, how do you plan to log in to these services?

Comment: I never use the same email twice, and the email address is created with an anonymous provider, via TOR. I'd say I got that covered ;-)
Concerning the other part of your comment, what do you mean by "There are lots of websites that show you what they know about you"?? A website that can tell me what does Dropbox knows about me? That's unlikely, but I'd be interested...

Comment: @ace25: You say that you don't know what Dropbox sees and logs on information from you but you don't know the same for any other site you visit including the anonymous provider for emails. You have to rely on what Tails offers here, i.e. to make sure that your original IP address (and associated information like rough geographic location) is not visible to the server - and nothing more. This is also independent of the service you use. The rest is trust into the service the same as you trust  your anonymous email provider. I.e. it essentially boils down to product recommendations - off topic.

Comment: OnionShare is easy to use.